# What is the order of additional parameters passed in jQuery.proxy?

Tags: jquery

JQuery provides a method called [jQuery.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) that allows one to pass in additional parameters to a function that are not supplied on the original caller.  However, the documentation does not state what order those parameters are supplied to the receiving function.  What is the order of receipt?

for example:

```
function f(a,b,c) {
   console.log(a,b,c);
}

var p = jQuery.proxy(f, null, 1, 2);
p(3);
```

What would be the values of a, b and c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additional parameters passed explicitly in the new function returned by `jQuery.proxy()` are passed in as the **first** parameters to the called function.  Any parameters passed to the call of the proxied function follow the additional parameters.  So in the code posed in the question, the resulting output would be:

`1,2,3`

This may seem like a meaningless question and answer, but an equally valid alternative definition may have been that actual parameters came first in a proxy resulting in a possible answer of:

`3,1,2`

Care needs to be taken when using proxies where the call to the proxied function is outside of your control.  For example:

```
function myHandler(value1, value2, event) {
 ...
}
$("button").click($.proxy(myHandler, null, "value1", "value2"));
```

would be needed to capture and handle the `event`parameter in addition to your added parameters.